# Jquery not loading data from mentioned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This works:

```
var myvar;
$.get('formElements.html', function(data) {
   myvar = data;
});
```

This doesn't work:

```
var myvar;
$.get('formElements.html .className', function(data) {
   myvar = data;
});
```

I wanna **get contents** from a div present in some other file and wanna **store inside myvar(a variable)**

Answer (score 1):

Data will be the content of the html file so you need to apply a selector on the content of data. You do this like this:

```
var myvar;
$.get('formElements.html', function(data) {
   myvar = $(data).find('.className').html();
});
```

Comment: $.get('loadin.php', function(data) {
  var myvar = $(data).find('#idstorerdiv').html();
  var wmid = myvar.replace(/\D/g,'');
  alert(''+myvar+'x'+wmid+'');
});
> it says **Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to get the textual value stored in `#idstorerdiv` based on your comment above.

Ensure you set the data type to html to be sure, although shouldn't be necessary. I also could not get `.html()` to work, but using `.text()` instead seems to work fine for me, as in:

```
$.get('loadin.php',{data: "html"}, function(data) { 
    var myvar = $(data).find('#idstorerdiv').text();
});
```

I see your code above you are using some `.replace()` functions which are bombing - using `.text()` should help with this.

Comment: and to test, add a `console.log` (or ugh, alert) after `var myvar = $(data).find('#idstorerdiv').text();` like this: `console.log(myvar)` to test what is coming back before you put the `.replace()` in there

Comment: $.get('loadmsgthree.php',{data: "html"}, function(data) {
  var myvar = $(data).find('#idstorerdiv').text();
  console.log(myvar);
  alert(myvar);
    });

this gives a blank alert!

Comment: what is in your html? more specifically the `#idstorerdiv` element?